# Which species of bumblebee(?) is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I observed this beautiful insect near a forest in northern Switzerland. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that looks like a "hover fly" — specifically the [Pellucid Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volucella_pellucens) (*[Volucella pellucens](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/52480-Volucella-pellucens)*).

Compare with:
[image: from: https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/pellucid-fly, by: David Gould]

This species is present throughout Europe according to the wikipedia article (first link).